# Is it ok to power an Arduino Duemilanove with 15 V?

Tags: arduino, power-supply

The documentation says 12V is the max tension recommended to power a Arduino Duemilanove, however the "limit" is 20V (see: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove).

Will the Arduino Duemilanove be OK if I power it with a 15V battery? I am using a shield on top of it, maybe it will be worse because of the heating?

*Additionnal information: I will use the VIN pin to provide current to motors (up to 2A). I think there is no impact on the Arduino (because I will not draw power from the Arduino, but from the VIN that is directly connected to the battery), but I'm not sure of that.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Powering motors from the same supply as the Arduino is likely to cause problems with the noise from the motors affecting the AVR. Using separate power supplies is advisable. If you really want to power the Arduino from 15V, put a suitable heatsink on the regulator, or use another regulator (a switcher, perhaps) to lower the voltage.

Comment: Because the regulator basically converts the difference between input and output voltage into heat.